# R.java / Refresh / Clean not Updating Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, user-interface

I used a project sample that originally had some placeholder images of sorts. However, now I'm currently in the stage of updating and experimenting with the images; I want to use a different set of images. Rather than create a new resource I did the following:

1. Open up playbuttonsm.png from res/drawable DIR via MS Paint
2. Erase placeholder logo, replace with new logo, and save
3. Via Eclipse, refresh res/, refresh R.java, run clean project

However, somehow despite rebuilding, the images won't update and still have the old play/pause images. I've also tried rebooting, restarting Eclipse, and re-importing the project.

**UPDATE:** Cleaning seems to 'restore' the images on my Windows DIR to before I made the image changes. Not sure if that helps people any in figuring out the source issue.

**EDIT:**

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.glowingpigs.tutorialstreamaudiopart1b"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="com.glowingpigs.tutorialstreamaudiopart1b.myPlayService" />
    </application></manifest>
```

**bin\res\drawable-hdpi (and other drawable folders snapshot):**

Before image change:
[image]

After image change:
[image]

And then it changes back to 'before changes' if I clean the project.

Comment: Does it happen on your device? i mean you see old logo

Comment: Yep, the old logo happens on my device

Comment: So the only one way is to re-install your Application

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android app, but it didn't fix the solution. :(

Comment: I would also say to try and delete your /bin folder in your project and let Ant build the project again. I've ran into this issues before and that has worked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you have replaced all the drawable folders including
   drawble-mdpi /drawable-hdpi etc...
2. Make sure your manifest is using your new logo.
3. Uninstall and then install your app again.

Comment: I did #1, and even posted the updated logo.png file in all of the drawable DIRs even though it was originally in only one, drawable-hdpi. The original file path hasn't changed nor has the filename, so I shouldn't need to update the manifest because there's no path/name to update. When I Run As > Android application and it runs on my phone via USB, the console seems to indicate it wipes over the previous version and re-installs (although the app itself isn't launchable through the app selection screen [doesn't exist there])

Comment: #3 is the key. The system/launcher keeps your logo cached. Uninstall the whole thing and it should update.

Comment: Ah, I thought R.java might be the one with the caching issues. I would have thought clearing the RAM up through Android Task Manager would have forced the app to re-pull from drawable and re-cache, but I guess not. Currently away from my source code, but I'll upvote/mark as answer when I get back to my IDE if this fixes it

Comment: I uninstalled from Android, and did Run As again, but it's still using the old logo that was in logo.png in the UI and not the new one that was saved.

Comment: post manifest, and screen shot of drawable folders please. I have never ran into this issue after checking all 3 points.

Comment: Manifest and before/after images posted

Comment: `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` change ic_launcher to YOUR drawable name. please rename it into your_app_launcher.

Comment: So, change the code to `android:icon="@drawable/your_app_launcher"` and change the file `ic_launcher` in all the drawable files to `your_app_launcher`?

Comment: Well the issue somewhat randomly resolved itself, during one of my re-cleans it repopulated with the 'old' images, and I replaced with the new images...again, and when I compiled the new images finally stuck, not sure what the root cause was, but I could honestly care less at this point. XD

Answer (score 2):

Just Delete the Bin folder of your Project in eclipse and Build your project again. Your images will get reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the res in your bin folder and do not change the name of the icon keep it ic_launcher. Also create a new buttons and use your PNG images on the new buttons and set up the onClicks again to the right method. Clean, restart your project.